# GWT GUI Application not getting loaded on Apache Tomcat 7.0.39

Tags: apache, firefox, gwt, tomcat7, windows-vista

I have a GWT GUI (getmap) application and i have placed it at ***\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps*** directory.

Now when i am trying to open it using http://:8080/getmap/GetMap.html>, i am getting an error " Requested Resource is not available"

But when i copy same GWT GUI Application under  ***\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\examples*** directory and load it using http://:8080/examples/getmap/GetMap.html>, everything works perfectly !!!

This problem is faced on Windows Vista.

I wold appreciate if anybody could provide some pointers to get rid of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

`webapps` contains WAR files or their *exploded* equivalent (i.e. a folder with a `WEB-INF` subfolder containing a `web.xml` file). The *root* of the server (served at the URL `/`) is a special webapp named `ROOT`.

So either create a `ROOT` webapp, or make `getmap` a *webapp* by adding the necessary `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

**DISCLAIMER:** the above is overly simplified and might not be accurate; plase check the Servlets spec and/or the Tomcat docs about deployment.